# Java-Error trying to sort an int

Tags: java

```
package programame;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class E100 {
public static int ascendente(int a) 
{
    String str = Integer.toString(a);
    String max[] = str.split("");
    Arrays.sort(max);
    String str1 = Arrays.toString(max);
    int ascendente = Integer.parseInt(str1);
    return ascendente;
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int intentos = sc.nextInt();
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(ascendente(x));
    }
}
```

Hi, I am trying to sort an int read from a scanner, but everytime I run it it gives me the error =

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[3, 4, 6, 7]"   at
 java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)     at
 java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)    at
 programame.E100.ascendente(E100.java:18)    at
 programame.E100.main(E100.java:25)

 C:\Users\agn12\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

Comment: please post the complete stack trace

Comment: Arrays.toString puts "[" "]" brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to split the number 3467 into its constituent decimal digits, sort them, and re-construct the digits into a single string:

```
String max[] = str.split("");
Arrays.sort(max);
String str1 = Arrays.toString(max);
```

The problem is that `Arrays.toString` returns a human-readable representation of the array, which is in the form "[3, 4, 6, 7]". This, obviously, cannot be parsed as an int. You are expecting to get the string "3467".

A better way of doing it (in terms of runtime efficiency and ease of coding) is to split the string into individual characters, instead of one-character strings. Then you can sort them, and easily turn them back into a string using one of String's constructors:

```
char[] max = str.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(max);
String str1 = new String(max);
```

The rest of your code can stay the same.

Comment: I tried it but gives me the error "char[] cannot be converted to String[]"

Comment: @A.Gisbert Apologies, max is a char array, not a string array. See corrected edit.

Answer (score 1):

The exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[3, 4, 6, 7]"
```

says that Java cannot convert such string to an Int as you are requesting.
It can be of use to be able to read the compiler error:

> programame.E100.ascendente(E100.java:18)    at
>
> programame.E100.main(E100.java:25)

It tells you that the problem arises at line 25 in method main of E100.java, that in turn calls the method ascendente and the problem is at line 18 where you try to convert to an int an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

The fault is with this line

String str1 = Arrays.toString(max);

You are trying to convert an array of numbers to string so 
max = [2]

So str1 = "[2]"

and then converting this to a number

int ascendente = Integer.parseInt(str1);

Gives an error ::  java.lang.NumberFormatException